# Sending XML in Query String

Tags: java

I am integrating USPS Web API in my Java application. I have to send a request of the form

```
http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll?API=CityStateLookup&XML=<CityStateLookupRequest%20USERID="XXXNORTH3110"> <ZipCode ID= "0"> <Zip5>22102</Zip5> </ZipCode> </CityStateLookupRequest>
```

Now hitting this on the browser works fine. But using this from the JAVA code breaks. How can I send XML in the Query String?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html

Comment: Encode xml data in url or send as a payload of HTTP POST request .

Comment: I would suggest also using a POST request, not a GET. GETs have a limited length.

Comment: Encoding the URL the server returns an error. Is their no way to send the request "as is" without any encoding.

Answer (score 1):

Why you should use POST to send this type of data: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp
In the POST body you don't need to encode the XML, you just need to set the correct content type "application/xml". Of course that only applies if it is valid XML and does not contain char are not allowed by XML standard.